# How can I improve my question on McWhorter's explanation of why some verbs are inherent reflexive?

Tags: discussion

Can you please recommend how I can clarify [How does 'remembering something' vs. 'remembering is something that happens to you' explain Inherent Reflexive Verbs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/28293/5306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make it self contained. 'inherent reflexive' isn't mentioned in your post.
2. Link to the right things 'inherent reflexive' isn't explained in the links (do #1 takes priority, but you shouldn't link to irrelevant things either).
3. Give examples (hopefully from the wild, but at the least make some up (really, from the wild is best)).
4. "Can 1 and 2 (colored in grey) be distinguished?" Where are 1 and 2 mentioned *anywhere*.

All these problems come up with in the first 3 lines. None of it makes sense.